repeated auto cmake configure causes extension host to die
since visual studio code version 1.92 i have been experiencing the following behavior:
all of a sudden the cmake configure will run repeatedly and then i get a message that extension host has died. all tools vanish from the bottom toolbar including the cmake configure, etc. and intellisense, compiling stop working. the only recourse is to exit visual studio code and then start again. for a while all goes well and then the same thing happens.
i removed all extensions and then re-installed the ones i needed but it didn't help.
this is on Ubuntu 22.04.
please help.

are you able to get log messages from the output panel before it dies? if so, please add them to your question post.
